# React add child table in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable in my react application. On clicking a button in a row I want to show a child datatable. I was able to do it using jQuery. The problem is that there is a button in the child table header and on clicking it I want to open a modal in react, and is not working. Here is the code.

```
row.child(
                        '<div class="ShowTable">' +
                        '<div class="TableHeader">' +
                        '<h4>Server - ' + rowData.ip + '</h4>' +
                        '<div><button type="button" class=" text-nowrap" onclick="Show(true)"> Push</button></div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<table class="child_table" id = "child_details' + index + '" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
                        '<thead><tr><th>S/N</th><th>Domain</th><th>File Transfer</th><th>Status</th><th>Push</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody>' +
                        '</tbody></table>' +
                        '</div>').show();
```

So instead I am trying to write it in react and the code is below

```
ReactDOM.render(
                        <td colSpan={6}>
                        <div className="ShowTable">
                            <div className="TableHeader">
                                <h4>Server - {rowData.ip}</h4>
                                <div><button type="button" className="text-nowrap" onClick={e => { Show(true) }}>Bulk Push</button></div>
                            </div>
                            <table className="child_table" id={`child_details${index}`} cellPadding={5} cellSpacing={0} border="0" style={{paddingLeft:"50px"}}>
                                <thead><tr><th>S/N</th><th>Domain</th><th>File Transfer</th><th>Status</th><th>Push</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody>
                                </tbody></table>
                        </div >
                        </td>
                        , row.node())
```

Here the button click works, but the problem is instead of child table it is replacing the current parent table row. It is because I am using `row.node()`. So how can I show it as child table? I want to get the child `tr`. I have tried `row.child().node()` but it is not working. Or is there a way I can call react function from jQuery? So that I can use the first code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using below code.

```
row.child('').show()

ReactDOM.render(
                        <td colSpan={6}>
                        <div className="ShowTable">
                            <div className="TableHeader">
                                <h4>Server - {rowData.ip}</h4>
                                <div><button type="button" className="text-nowrap" onClick={e => { Show(true) }}>Bulk Push</button></div>
                            </div>
                            <table className="child_table" id={`child_details${index}`} cellPadding={5} cellSpacing={0} border="0" style={{paddingLeft:"50px"}}>
                                <thead><tr><th>S/N</th><th>Domain</th><th>File Transfer</th><th>Status</th><th>Push</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead><tbody>
                                </tbody></table>
                        </div >
                        </td>
                        , row.child()[0])
```

First I added the child row and then used `row.child()[0]` to get the row and passed  it to the `ReactDOM.render()` function